# SelectMany cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, linq

I get the following error when I try to compile my code:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

```
        List<RowEntry> entries = ...
        List<RowArgument> arguments = ...

        var argumentsVal = entries.SelectMany((RowEntry entry) =>
            (IEnumerable<RowArgumentVal>)arguments.SelectMany((RowArgument arg) => 
            new RowArgumentVal()
            {
                Action = "X" 
                , EntryID = entry.ID
                , ArgID = arg.ID
                , Val_BIT = true
                , Val_DATE = new DateTime(2014, 01, 04)
                , Val_DATETIME = new DateTime(2014, 01, 04)
                , Val_DECIMAL = 4.6M
                , Val_INT = 88
                , Val_TIME = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0)
            }
        ).Cast<RowArgumentVal>()).Cast<RowArgumentVal>().ToList();
```

I don't get how I can "type" this even further...

Comment: `SelectMany` is intended to get a list of children entities in `RowEntry` instances, while you are trying to do a cartesian product it seems?

Comment: A cartesian product indeed.

Comment: Make the inner `SelectMany` into a simple `Select`

Comment: Use just `Select` instead `SelectMany`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that the inner `SelectMany` isn't applicable there, and you probably meant `Select`.

```
var argumentsVal = entries.SelectMany(entry =>
    arguments.Select(arg => new RowArgumentVal())).ToList();
```

Each `entry` will be mapped into an `IEnumerable<RowArgumentVal>` according to the `arguments`.

Imagine the outer `SelectMany` was a simple `Select`, and it would generate `List<IEnumerable<RowArgumentVal>>`. But because it is `SelectMany`, it will "flatten" the result into a simple `List<RowArgumentVal>`.

The `SelectMany` method expects a mapping to `IEnumerable<T>` - not `T`. Your original code would be valid if `RowArgumentVal` just happened to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, which I suppose isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a cartesian product from both lists since there is no relation between them. You may want to join them but it's not exactly clear how.

Here is a more readable and compiling way to produce a cartesian product:

```
var query = from entry in entries
            from argument in arguments
            select new RowArgumentVal
            {
               Action = "X", EntryID = entry.ID,  ArgID = argument.ID, // ...
            };

List<RowArgumentVal> argumentsVal = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a cartesian product try doing the following

```
 var argumentsVal = from e in entries
    from a in arguments
    select new RowArgumentVal(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, the "further typing" you could have done would be to give the type arguments to the generic method calls. In particular, if you had changed the second `SelectMany` to `SelectMany<RowArgument, RowArgumentVal>` you would have got the errors

> Cannot implicitly convert type `RowArgumentVal` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RowArgumentVal>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type `System.Func<RowArgument,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RowArgumentVal>>` because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

which would maybe have led you to the other answers here - that you were trying to call a method that expected a sequence, but you were giving it a single object.

(Or in trying to decide which type arguments to add, you would have realised what was wrong sooner.)