# Get distinct values of List in List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm struggling with a db application, where I need to get the distinct values. The whole structure looks somewhat like this

```
class A
{
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
class B
{
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}
class C
{
    public int x {get; set;}
}
```

This is the model from a db and I have a subset of all `A's`. Now I need to get all `distinct` values `C.x` from all those `A's`. 
So basically something like

```
db.A.Where(something).SelectMany(s => s.Bs.SelectMany(t => t.C.x).ToList().Distinct()).ToList()
```

But it tells me, that the second `SelectMany` cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602923/selectmany-cannot-infer-type-argument-why-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code like this:

```
SelectMany(s => s.Bs.Select(t => t.C.x)
```

Note that `B` is not a member of `A` but `Bs`, and also your second `SelectMany` should be `Select`.

Read more https://stackoverflow.com/a/25564528/2946329

Comment: you're right, the second one had to be `Select`, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this? Also I think it'll be needed to add `.Include` statements:

```
db.A.Where(something)/*.Include(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.C))*/
    .SelectMany(x => x.Bs.Select(b => b.C.x)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Strange, my `Where(x)` does not allow `.Include` afterwads

Comment: You need to add a reference to the `System.Data.Entity`. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_1