# Nested LINQ Select is returning IEnumerable of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following code:

```
var purchaseItems = this.GetMenuItemRows().Select(
                    a => a.DishListItemRow.GetDishIngredientRows().Select(
                        b => b.PurchaseItemRow));
```

The LINQ expression is returning result of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PurchaseItemRow>>`

**How do I get a result of type `IEnumerable<PurchaseItemRow>`?**

Comment: Try using `SelectMany` instead of your first `Select`.

Comment: Use `SelectMany` something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47221191/2946329

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **`SelectMany`**

```
var purchaseItems = this.GetMenuItemRows().SelectMany(
                    a => a.DishListItemRow.GetDishIngredientRows().Select(
                        b => b.PurchaseItemRow));
```